# Concrete function as default template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, metaprogramming

Is it possible in C++ to set as default template argument concrete (free) function?

I mean something like that:

```
void foo() {}

template <typename F = foo>
struct C 
{
    F f;
};
```

Comment: Templates come in two flavours - either you can have a template on different classes (like `std::vector`) or a template on values of objects (like `std::array` second template argument - size). Which one do you want? Your code suggest first, but your question suggests second.

Comment: Consider wrapping `foo` in a function object type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function pointer is a *non-type* template parameter.

```
template <auto F = &foo> // c++17
template <void(*F)() = &foo>
```

Here is a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() { std::puts("foo"); }
void bar() { std::puts("bar"); }

template <void (*F)() = &foo>
struct Foo {
  void exec() { F(); }
};

int main() {
  Foo a;
  Foo<&bar> b;

  a.exec(); // prints "foo"
  b.exec(); // prints "bar"
}
```

If you have to store the function pointer for some reason (like you did in your snippet), you can do it by declaring `decltype(F) f = F;` as a class member.